# Rails error: can't convert Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Using the google maps API and rails 3.2.1 I have page allowing to move the business marker on a map to correct it's position. The business model has latitude and longitude (amongst others). The relevant part is:

```
<%= form_for :business, :url => { :action => "updatemap" }, :id => 'updatebutton' do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :latitude %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :longitude %>
  <br />
  <%= f.submit "Save"  %>
<% end %>
```

The method updatemap is:

```
def updatemap
  @business = Business.find(params[:id])
  @business.latitude = params([:business][:latitude])
  @business.longitude = params([:business][:longitude])
  if @business.save!
    redirect_to business_path(@business), :flash => { :success => "The business was updated!" }
  else
    render 'changemap', :flash => { :error => "An error occured." }
  end
end
```

Running the debugger, params([:business][:latitude]) and params([:business][:longitude]) give the correct value of the new map coordinates (e.g. "45.273739" for latitude). But there is an error:

TypeError in BusinessesController#updatemap
can't convert Symbol into Integer
(the line of the error is the @business.latitude = params([:business][:latitude]) line)

I also tried with

```
...
if @business.update_attributes(params[:business])
...
```

but the error is the same. What causes the error and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing `params([:business][:latitude])` rather than `params[:business][:latitude]`. That means that `[:business]` is actually a method call on `self`, rather than `params`. Presumably the class which this code is part of has a `[]` method, but it expects an integer rather than `:business`.

Comment: Unfortunately there is the same error. Here is the params-hash for information:

Comment: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"Vc9QPHBQjnftzfzutfNpOyftX+eDVoFjUSzVs9M=",
 "business"=>{"latitude"=>"44.976565607846",
 "longitude"=>"8.89413124999999"},
 "commit"=>"Save",
 "id"=>"1"}

Comment: By the way: also to_s.to_f or just .to_f gives me the same error message.

Comment: Just for an experiment, try `@business.latitude = 10` or something like that. See if it still gives you the same error. If so, it has nothing to do with the params. Also, why do you write `params([:business][:latitude])` rather than `params[:business][:latitude]`?

Comment: Hi Alex, yes, with any values (like e.g. 10) the error disappears, but it doesn't save the new value into the database. Good question about the brackets... I deleted them and the error message disappears, but again not saving the new position. Anyhow, one error seems to be solved now :-)

Comment: @user929062, I just edited my answer to reflect the true problem which was causing your `TypeError`. Please accept! The fact that the data is still not saving is a different problem, and I suggest you post a separate question for that one.